# Using Project tool in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, datum

I am trying to get my shapefiles to line up using the project tool.

This is the information of the "Input Dataset or Feature Class"

Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class
Shapefile:  C:tl_2016_69110_edges.shp
Geometry Type:  Line
Coordinates have Z values:  No
Coordinates have measures:  No

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

This is the information of the map that I am trying to align **tl_2016_69110_edges.shp** to.
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class
Shapefile:  C:Saipan_Floodmasks.shp
Geometry Type:  Polygon
Coordinates have Z values:  No
Coordinates have measures:  No

Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_55N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   147.00000000
Scale_Factor:   0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian: Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

The location that I am trying to align is Saipan. I think I need to specify a "Geographic Transformation," since I want to convert between WGS 1984 Datum and NAD 1983 Datum. I tried using
"WGS_1984_(ITRF08)_To_NAD_1983_MA11" in the "Geographic Transformation" section, but this didn't change anything.

I've attached a picture of my problem. There is a pier (the rectangle protruding from the shore) and the blue flood mask should be directly over it. [image]

Comment: Project can't solve data quality issues. Coastlines in particular have dozens of definitions of what "land" and "wayer" are.

Comment: @Vince But, it seems as if the blue flood mask just needs to be shifted down by a few meters.

Comment: So shift it then. NAD83 doesn't seem appropriate outside of North America, but it's rare that a datum shift only translates in one dimension. I've had authoritative data sources shift by hundreds of meters between snapshots, which messed up a year's worth of processing. It happens

Comment: To compliment @Vince pointing out definitions of coastline, another source of disparity can be down to data capture scale, your flood polygons look generalised to me which may indicate they were captured at a different scale and an off-set was introduced that way? If they are generalised then a manual shift is probably the path of least resistance.